# If condition in mySQL query with join in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Good Day!

Is it possible to apply `if condition` in the `query` in `codeigniter: model`?
I have this query in `Model`:

```
function activity($id) {        
        $this->db->select('a.ID, a.activityID, r.roleName');
        $this->db->from('activity a');
        $this->db->join('role r', 'r.ID = a.activityID');
        $this->db->where('a.ID', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

And in my view I want to show the `ID and activityID from table activity` and also the counter part `roleName (from table role) of activityID`.
But the tricky part is that the value in `activityID` is not just a simple `INT`, like this:

```
ID  ActivityID
1   5,7,9
2   2,4
3   
4   10
5   1,6
```

So I'm thinking to use if condition in the query, like if the activityID value not contains comma (,) it will use join like this: `$this->db->join('role r', 'r.ID = a.activityID');` then get the `r.roleName`.
Example:

```
ID  ActivityID  Role Name
4   10          Basketball
```

But if contains comma (,), it will `explode` by comma (,) then join like this: `$this->db->join('role r', 'r.ID = a.activityID');` but it will output also by roleName with comma in between.
Example:

```
ID  ActivityID  Role Name
1   5,7,9       Tennis,Football,Soccer
2   2,4         Volleyball,Chess
```

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Junction Tables were invented to solve this problem, it'd be worth your while to read up on that (and normalisation) instead of storing multiple IDs in a single comma-separated field.

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad idea to have comma separated ids in your column you should first normalize your structure other wise it will lead you more expensive problems,for now you use [*FIND_IN_SET()*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) ,for having role names also as comma separated you can use [*GROUP_CONCAT*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> Be ware of that fact it has a default limit of 1024 characters to concat but it can be increased which is defined in manual

```
SELECT 
a.ID, 
GROUP_CONCAT(a.activityID) activityID,
GROUP_CONCAT(r.roleName) roleName
  FROM activity a
  LEFT JOIN `role` r ON(FIND_IN_SET(r.ID,a.activityID) > 0);
  WHERE a.ID = $id
  GROUP BY a.ID
```

For CI use `query()` function for above query

> Please first have a look at [**Database Normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)